# 500px API key in development

Tags: node.js, api, key, consumer, 500px

I'm building an Node.js app and I want to get content from my 500px account so I try to use the API. For that I need to generate a consumer key but to do that I need an website URL, for now I'm only in dev so I don't have a domain name... How I can manage that and go through ?

Thx

Comment: Why imagine a complex workaround? Can't you just create a free landing page somewhere and use it as such?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "create a free landing page somewhere"... I need an API key from 500px and they ask for a domain name but I don't have one. I suppose that I can't put a random one because they probably control the origin access when you use the API...

Comment: Is this a wild guess? Before I am sure of this, I would hunt for the easiest solution first...

Comment: It was a wrong guess... Actually you can put anything and the API key will work ! Thank's for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can put anything and the API key will work !